# Como cadastrar no banco do Wordpress a partir do advanced custom field

Tags: wordpress

No meu site tem como inserir novos albuns de fotos a partir do ACF.
Criei uma tabela no banco de dados que contém as informações do album, como nome, local, data e etc. Só que eu não faço ideia como inserir essas informações do album no banco de dados.

Creio que o código da inserção seja assim, mas não sei como relacionar isso ao ACF.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "bd";


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Conectado!";


$nome_album = $_POST['nome_album']; //Seria o nome que o usuário adiciona no form do ACF
$local_album = $_POST['local_album'];
$data_album = $_POST['data_album'];


$query = "INSERT INTO albums (nome_album, local_album, data_album)
VALUES ('$nome_album', '$local_album', '$data_album')";

if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {
    echo "cadastro realizado com sucesso";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Olha, não é recomendado você manipular a base de dados do Wordpress dessa maneira, se você vai usar o ACF para criar campos é ideal que se faça tudo por ele. Analisando o seu cenário eu recomendaria:

1. Criar um Custom Post Type chamado ALBUNS. Você pode fazer usando o plugin Custom Post Type UI - https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/

Aqui você tem duas opções:

2.1. Criar custom fields usando o ACF associando ao CUSTOM POST TYPE criado.

2.2. Criar taxonomias personalizadas chamadas LOCAL e DATA (a vantangem daqui na minha opinião é que é mais facil de fazer o sistema busca padrão do WP enxergar). Você pode fazer também usando o plugin Custom Post Type UI - https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/

Dessa forma você protege sua base dados e usa os próprios recursos do WP para organizar os dados que precisa.

Comment: Muito obrigada @Felipe, eu não conhecia esse plugin Custom Post Type, vou dar uma olhada na documentação dele. Valeu mesmo pela dica!!